# Can a light fixture be added to a ceiling fan already installed with speed switch control?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I have a ceiling fan already installed with one 3 speed wall switch when I bought the house. I would like to add a light fixture, but don't know how I will turn it on/off. I know I can't use the speed switch for the light and there isn't separate wiring in the wall for the light.

Comment: Is a pull chain on/off at the light fixture an option?

Comment: @JACK A pull chain is a possible solution if it is panel->fan[with light added] ->switch (i.e., switch loop). If it is panel->switch->fan then pull chain won't work because the power will all be affected by the 3-speed switch.

Comment: Is there a light kit even available for the fan? You can't just "hang a light on the fan" - it has to be designed for it.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Right!  I figured I'd ask the easiest question first.. :-)

Comment: to get wall controls possibly you will need to put one or both features (fan and light) on a wireless remote control.  more details of how it's wired will help.

Comment: It's possible that there's a 3rd wire in the cable leading from the switch to the fan. Turn the power off at the breaker, remove the cover plate from the switch, unscrew the switch from the wall (do _NOT_ disconnect any wires from anything!), then take a picture of the switch and wires inside the box in the wall and [edit] it into your question. Then reverse everything to put it back together. Based on the pics, this _could_ be a piece of cake. Or, it could be rather difficult.

Comment: A picture of the ceiling fan itself would also help. Are you trying to integrate a new light fixture to an existing ceiling fan, or is the idea to mount it on the side, using the same socket?

Comment: I took off the plate and inspected the 3 speed switch wiring. I observed a blue, red, black and white wires. I wonder if the fan has already been wired for a light, but the previous owner never installed one. I'm guessing a pull chain might do the trick. I will try to install a fixture over the weekend. Update to come. Thanks all.

Comment: I just discovered the dial switch does not change speed even though it is a speed switch. It acts as an on/off switch no matter the setting, so I guess pull chain is going to work. Thanks.

Comment: I learned the blue wire under the ceiling cup was not attached. I joined it with the black wires and the light fixture worked. Now I can't use both the fan and the light at the same time. When I have the light on and pull the chain for the fan the light goes off. If I turn the fan off the light works. I only have black, white and ground wires in the ceiling feed. Was I supposed to join the blue light wire to white?